# php in_array returning stdClass error

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array (getyears) which I am struggling to reference, to return a 'checked' state.

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[23]
      public 'year' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[25]
      public 'year' => string '3' (length=1)
```

I am using in_array which somewhat works, however returns the Severity: Notice  Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

```
 $array = (array)$getyears;
 if(in_array(2, $array)){
     echo ' checked';
 }
```

Comment: If you are only checking for an aray index. You might be better of using `array_key_exists`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have array of objects. You need to get years from object in it. Something like:

```
$extractYears = function($obj) {
    return $obj->year;
};

return in_array(2, array_map($extractYears, $yourArray));
```

Comment: Thanks, this got it going.  Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a method `getAsArray()` in the class of which `$getyears` is an object from.

So you access `$array = $getyears->getAsArray()`.

You can't search in an object, your code makes simply this (pseudocode)
`$array[0] == 2`, but `$array[0]` is a class, so this could not be done.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
*
* Convert an object to an array
*
* @param    object  $object The object to convert
* @reeturn      array
*
*/
function objectToArray( $object )
{
    if( !is_object( $object ) && !is_array( $object ) )
    {
        return $object;
    }
    if( is_object( $object ) )
    {
        $object = get_object_vars( $object );
    }
    return array_map( 'objectToArray', $object );
}

/*** convert the array to object ***/
$array = objectToArray( $obj );
```

more details shows in http://www.phpro.org/examples/Convert-Object-To-Array-With-PHP.html